# отправка почты в outlook. Не приходит письмо

Tags: javascript, php

Отправляю письмо с хостинга средствами php Функции mail()

```
$message = '  <table  width="width: 600px">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px">Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </table>';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
if (mail("test@outlook.com" ,"Новая заявка", $message,$headers))
 {     
    echo "Отправлено";
} else {
    echo "При отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}
```

Письмо нормально приходит на почтовые ящики гугла(test@gmail.com) но не приходит в test@outlook.com

Comment: А у вас и в правду есть почта вида `test@outlook.com` или `test@gmail.com`?

Comment: Это для визуального отображения, почта имеет название вида name.lastname@outlook.com

Comment: А у вас происходит какая-то ошибка или просто письма не приходят? Попробуйте проверить папку *спам*.

Comment: Ошибок не отдает, но письмо ни в спам ни куда более не приходит

Comment: Ну раз письмо приходит на gmail, значит оно уходит с вашего сервера, но не доходит от оутлука или блокируется им. Следовательно, в приведенном коде нету ошибок и разбираться надо с оутлуком. Для очистки совести попробуйте еще какой-нибудь ящик на мейле, яндексе или где-нибудь еще.